# Extract n characters after pattern in string in R

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I have a long string with mupltiple instances of pattern. I want the n characters following the pattern. Say that my string is `"quick fox jumps over the lazy dog"` and I want the two characters after every `"u"`. i.e. I would want a vector `c("ic", "mp")` as my output. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar but using `str_extract_all` with `paste0`:

key points:
`(?<=)` is a lookbehind, that matches the pattern but **does not include** it in the extracted string.

`.{n}`matches the next `n` characters after the pattern.

```
library(stringr)

n <- 2
str_extract_all(string, paste0("(?<=", "u", ").{", n, "}"))[[1]]

[1] "ic" "mp"
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `str_extract_all` - create a function (with arguments for the string, `n` - number of characters, after and the `chr` - for the character to match

```
library(stringr)
f1 <- function(string, n, chr)
{
pat <- sprintf("(?<=%s)%s", chr, strrep(".", n))
str_extract_all(string, pat)[[1]]
}
```

-testing

```
> f1(str1, 2, "u")
[1] "ic" "mp"
> f1(str1, 3, "u")
[1] "ick" "mps"
```

#### data

```
 str1 <- "quick fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `regmatches` + `gregexpr`, along with the pattern `"(?<=u)[a-zA-Z]{2}"`:

```
> regmatches(s, gregexpr("(?<=u)[a-zA-Z]{2}", s, perl = TRUE))[[1]]
[1] "ic" "mp"
```